# Prove that $\big( n^2 - 1 \big) \mid \big( 2^{n!} - 1 \big) $

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, divisibility

Here's a problem from *104 Number Theory Problems*.

Prove that for any even positive integer $n$, $n^2-1$ divides $2^{n!} - 1$.

> *Solution.* Let $m=n+1$. We need to prove that $m(m-2)$ divides $2^{(m-1)!}-1$. Because $\phi(m)$ divides $(m-1)!$ we have $\left(2^{\phi(m)}-1\right) \mid \left(2^{(m-1)!} - 1 \right)$ and from
>   Euler's theorem, $ m \mid \left( 2^{\phi(m) - 1} \right) $, so it
>   follows that $ m \mid \left( 2^{(m-1)!} - 1 \right) $. Similarly, $ \left( m - 2 \right) \mid \left( 2^{(m-1)!} - 1 \right) $. Because $m$
>   is odd, $ \text{gcd}(m,m-2) = 1 $ and the conclusion follows. $\Box$

Uh, excuse me, how does $ \phi(m) \mid (m-1)! $ imply $ \left( 2^{\phi(m)}-1 \right) \mid \left( 2^{(m-1)!} - 1 \right) $ ?

Comment: In titles, left, right and displaystyle are discourage. See http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9687/guidelines-for-good-use-of-latex-in-question-titles for my information.

Comment: @dustin Thanks for editing!

Comment: See also: [Prove that for any even positive integer $n$, $n^2-1 \mid 2^{n!}-1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2126531).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$2^{ab}- 1 = (2^a -1)\left(\sum_{k=0}^{b-1}2^{ka}\right)$$

Comment: Oops, that completely slipped my mind; thanks a lot! I'll accept as soon as I can. :)

Comment: @AhaanRungta You are welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

I find it easier to see it this way.
$$
2^a\equiv1\pmod {2^a−1} ⇒2^{ab}\equiv1^b\equiv1 \pmod{2^a−1}
$$