# Find all positive integers $n$ such that $n^2-1|2^{n!}-1$

Tags: number-theory

What I have done so far:

- $n$ must be even
- $(n-1)(n+1)|2^{n!}-1$
- because $n-1$ and $n+1$ are odd, they are relatively prime
- so both $n-1$ and $n+1$ should divide $2^{n!}-1$

Then I get lost in how I should handle it.
Could anyone help me with that?

Comment: A better way to put it is that $n^2-1|2^{n!}-1$ iff $n\pm1$ both divide $2^{n!}-1$.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2126531/prove-that-for-any-even-positive-integer-n-n2-1-mid-2n-1, or https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1019141/prove-that-big-n2-1-big-mid-big-2n-1-big. It seems that this is true for all even $n$.

Comment: Thank you guys for your help. The solution seems clear;)